# Insert Column into Imported Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have code to import a table from Excel into Access but I want to be able to add a column with a header to the table. This column would then contain the number that was chosen as "x" for all rows. This should be explained by the attached code.

```
Private Sub Import_Click()

    Dim dlg As Object
    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(3)
    x = InputBox("Harvest Data Number:")

    With dlg
        .Title = "Select the Excel file to import"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx", 1
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 2

        If .Show = -1 Then
            StrFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "Harvest " & x & " Peptide Data", StrFileName, True, "DENOVO sorted by AMP!A21:Z"
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to populate a column which isn't present in the sheet, consider an append query instead of `TransferSpreadsheet`.  You can use a query parameter to get the value of *x* (*Harvest Data Number*).

This example pulls from *Sheet1$* in a workbook named *temp.xls* and stores those data in a table named *tblDestination*.  Note the source and destination field names can be different.

```sql
INSERT INTO tblDestination ([Harvest Data Number], fld2, fld3, fld4)
SELECT [x] AS [Harvest Data Number], s1.[Seq#], s1.Name, s1.Location
FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\SomeFolder\temp.xls].[Sheet1$] AS s1;
```

Comment: The problem with doing that is that it needs to be a simple button click on a form.

Comment: And so? That simple button click should just execute that Query instead of calling TransferSpreadsheet.

Comment: I guess I need to rephrase, the code needs to allow the user to select any excel spreadhseet (not just a specific file) then import that spreadsheet with the title "Harvest _ Peptide Data" where _ is a number chosen by the user that will link back to a different spreadsheet. The _ should be placed into a new column so that it can be linked using the autonumber from the other spreadsheet. Hope this helps explain better.